# PostgreSQL: WHERE IN and NOT WHERE IN

Tags: postgresql, where-in

I have two tables `A` and `B`, `A` referred to `B` by field `A.id_b B.id`, so that any `id_b` value present in `B.id`.

I have three queries:
First one:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.id_b
    FROM A a)
```

It gives me `0`;

Second one, difference only in `NOT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id IN (
    SELECT a.id_b
    FROM A a)
```

This query gives me: `1899`

Third one:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
```

And this query gives me `3599`

SAME result in:

```
SELECT a.id_b
FROM A a
```

guaranty me spliting `B.id` on two sets, and count of elements in both sets must much total elements count, but I have: **1899 + 0 != 3599**.

How that could be?

Comment: Yes, unique. Primary key. And A.id_b id foreign key, with NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: Side note: The last query does not have `COUNT` function. Is it intentionally?

Comment: No, that's just subquery from first two queries.

Comment: Be specific. is it `A.b_id` or `A.id_b`?

Comment: `A.id_b`, Two table, having for one column in each - `A: [id_b]` and `B: [id]`.

Comment: Instead of editing a question. You should (must) add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Didn't expect I can answer my own question... Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason. There was records in A, which has `NULL` values in `A.id_b`. That's why query:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.id_b
    FROM A a)
```

was returning `0`.

Answer (score 3):

This query tells us that table B has total of 3599 rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
```

Next query tells us that every single one id from B was used in A:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.id_b
    FROM A a)
```

Further, this query tells is that table B has 1899 id's that are mentioned in table A:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id IN (
   SELECT a.id_b
   FROM A a)
```

The only possible explanation to this is that some B.id were used in table A as A.id_b more than once per row.
Running this query will show list of all duplicate mentions of id_b in table A:

```
SELECT a.id_b
FROM A a
GROUP BY a.id_b
HAVING count(a.id_b) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well, yeah, rows from B using more then ones in table A. But how that effect on `NOT IN` selection? I have `0` B rows, which is not used in A and `1899` rows which is used. Where is the rest of?

Comment: In this query

    SELECT COUNT(b.id)
    FROM B b
    WHERE b.id IN (
        SELECT a.id_b
        FROM A a)

  IN (...) implicitly run unique selection. And it only found 1899 unique ones

Comment: And that's right, my question is where is the rest of elements from B, why they not appearing in `NOT IN` query.

Comment: Well, we can only conclude that 1700 'missing' B ids were never mentioned in table A. Is it possible that B has nulls?

Comment: Yes, but **WHY** the query `SELECT COUNT(b.id)
FROM B b
WHERE b.id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.id_b
    FROM A a)` gives me 0

Comment: Thanks, found the solution. Updated my question with it.

Comment: If B has nulls this can explain everything. In SQL, NULL handing can be considered weird. For example, nothing can be equal to NULL, even NULL itself. And NULL can never be member of any subset. And it cannot be NOT member of any subset. Strange, isn't it? :-)